# How do I figure out if a particular commit is in my current branch with EGit?

Tags: egit

I have a repository with many branches and I am tying to figure out if a particular commit (with a specific commit message) is in my current branch. I can find the "interesting" commit using the the find box at the bottom of the History view.

I tried following the vertical lines but there is so much line-crossing that I find it really hard to say if the commit is in or not.

Is there a way to see all commits that contributed to a particular branch as a single list?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a commit in the history view, look at the detail area for this commit. After author and committer details, you can see which branches contain the commit (Branches: ...). In case this area is hidden, open the view menu (the triangle) and check *Show* > *Revision Comment*.

You can also open the commit in a new window using the context menu and selecting *Open in Commit Viewer*.